# Does cypress support a retry fail threshold

Tags: cypress, cypress-fail-fast

I like cypress's built in behavior to support retries. However, I do not see a failure threshold after which to stop retrying tests. Say if 30% of the tests fail even after retry, something is very wrong and there is no reason to keep retrying the rest.

If something is wrong with the network or someone checks in a change that breaks the whole UX, then retrying all tests could take a long time, especially when combined with defaultCommandTimeout.

Is there support for this that I am missing? This is pretty standard in test frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea, but I guess there would be some variation in requirements. Here's some rough code to implement using a threshold count (not percentage).

- In the support file, add a control object where threshold is set and fails are counted
- Add an `on('fail')` listener to count the fails
- In `beforeEach()` hook check the counter and skip if threshold is exceeded

**cypress/support/e2e.js**

```js
const fails = {
  thresholdCount: 2,
  failCount: 0,
}

Cypress.on('fail', (error, test) => {
  fails.failCount++
  throw error
})

beforeEach(function () {
  if (fails.failCount > fails.thresholdCount) {
    this.skip()
  }
})
```

**Test**

```js
describe('failing tests', { defaultCommandTimeout: 300 }, () => {

  it('test1 -passes', { retries: 3 }, () => {
    expect(true).to.eq(true)
  })

  it('test2 - fails', { retries: 3 }, () => {
    expect(true).to.eq(false)
  })

  it('test2 - skipped', { retries: 3 }, () => {
    expect(true).to.eq(false)
  })
})
```

[image]